# Why my \AtBeginDocument and \AtEndDocument don't work in .sty file...?

Tags: environments, document-classes, filesystem-access

I'm looking to set up a class that allows me to type a document for both teacher (complete) and students (with holes instead of text) that is differentiated using an `\ifprof` boolean. My macros and my documents work well: I just have to put `\proftrue` or `\proffalse` at the beginning of the document and that's it. Only I would like these two documents to be in a single pdf one after the other at the end of the compilation via pdflatex.

So I imagined taking the complete contents of my `.tex` document, saving it in a `.cpy` attachment and calling it twice with the `\input{\jobname.cpy}` preceded each time by the `\proftrue` or `\proffalse`}.

So I tested saving the contents in a file with the `newfile.sty` package and the `writeverbatim` environment and here is my minimum file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \newoutputstream{contenu}
    \openoutputfile{\jobname.cpy}{contenu}

    \begin{writeverbatim}{contenu}
        \lipsum[1-2]
        \today
    \end{writeverbatim}

    \closeoutputstream{contenu}

    \input{\jobname.cpy} \newpage
    \input{\jobname.cpy}

    \end{document}
```

So I compiled with pdflatex and it works well! My document contains twice the lorem and the date, and the test2.cpy file contains just what is in the writeverbatim environment.

So I wanted to make a classetest.cls class that would allow me to stop worrying about these lines of code to save in a file and repeat my code twice, thanks to \AtBeginDocument and \AtEndDocument :

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} %version de latex utilisée
\ProvidesClass{classetest}[28/06/2020 Classe lycée,V1.0] %Nom de la classe sans le .cls

\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{newfile}

\AtBeginDocument{%

    \newoutputstream{contenu}
    \openoutputfile{\jobname.cpy}{contenu}
    \begin{writeverbatim}{contenu}
    }

\AtEndDocument{%

    \end{writeverbatim}
    \closeoutputstream{contenu}

    \input{\jobname.cpy} \newpage
    \input{\jobname.cpy}

    }
```

And I created the following test2.tex file:

```
\documentclass{classetest}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\today

\end{document}
```

But at the compilation : **! File ended while scanning use of \next. I suspect you have forgotten a ...**
and my test2.cpy' file contains: (all the early jibber-jabber is on one line)

```
{ver@color.sty}{\cs_set_protected:Npn \__color_backend_pickup:N ##1{\exp_last_unbraced:Nx \__color_backend_pickup:w {\current@color } 0 0 0\q_stop ##1}\cs_new_protected:Npn \__color_backend_pickup:w ##1 ##2 ##3 ##4 ##5 ##6\q_stop ##7{\str_if_eq:nnTF {##2}{g}{\tl_set:Nn ##7{gray ##1}}{\str_if_eq:nnTF {##4}{rg}{\tl_set:Nn ##7{rgb ##1 ##2 ##3}}{\str_if_eq:nnTF {##5}{k}{\tl_set:Nn ##7{cmyk ##1 ##2 ##3 ##4}}{\str_if_eq:nnTF {##2}{cs}{\tl_set:Nx ##7{spot \use_none:n ##1 ##5}}{\tl_set:Nn ##7{gray 0}}}}}}}\ifdim \topskip <1sp\global \topskip 1sp\relax \fi \global \@maxdepth \maxdepth \global \let \@begindocumenthook \@undefined \ifx \@listfiles \@undefined \global \let \@filelist \relax \global \let \@addtofilelist \@gobble \fi \gdef \do ##1{\global \let ##1\@notprerr }\@preamblecmds \global \let \@nodocument \relax \global \let \do \noexpand \ignorespaces 

\lipsum[1-2]
\today

\end{document}
```

I don't see my mistake. I don't know if what I want to do is impossible. I've searched and I haven't found it. I'm a simple cook and I'm not a witch. I'm not a witch to engage in `\def` or `\relax` or `\edef`. (But I'm willing to use them.)

I think I should take out the first and last lines of my test2.cpy file, but how do I do that?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: I'd say that it is most likely because verbatim material cannot be used inside arguments for macros. I also find this to be a very strange way of writing documents.